# Please choose a time at your convenience

Tags: time, email

Hi I am just writing an email to meet someone but I am letting him to choose the time.

Is it correct?.

*

> Then I will let you to choose the time for this meeting.

*

Comment: The verb _let_ never takes a to-infinitive: 'I will let you choose the time.' This is grammatical, but sounds rather condescending. 'Please choose a convenient time and let me know.' / 'Please let me know when a convenient time would be.'

Answer (score 4):

"I will let you choose the time for this meeting" would be correct.  No "to" is required.  This sounds, however, like you are deferring to the other person in some way, perhaps grudgingly.

I would tend to write "Please let me know a convenient time for the meeting" if I want the other person to choose a time.

Comment: Agreed. In any language, you are better off telling the person what you want them to do.